# What is the error in my code? The multiplication of my variables is not being displayed in the total

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to get my totalCost variable to display the multiplied value. I believe there may be something wrong with the IDs or the price variable. Is there a better way to write this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>    
       <Script type="text/javascript">    
          function multiply() {    
            var hoursParked = document.getElementById('hP').value;
            var price = 5.00;
            var totalCost = document.getElementById('total');
            var totalPayment = (hoursParked * price);
            totalCost.value= totalPayment;
          }    
      </Script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div align="center">
        <form id="1">
            <h1><p style="background-color:blue ; color:red;">Jamie's     Parking Garage Payment Calculator</p></h1><hr>
            <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName" placeholder="Please enter your name here." size="27px"><br><br>
            <input type="number" id="hP" name="hoursParked" placeholder="Hours parked?" min="1" max="24"><br><br>
            <input type="button" id="calculateP" name="calculatePayment" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply()"/>
            <input type="reset" id="resetBtn" value="Clear"><br><br>
            <input type="number" id="total" name="totalCost" placeholder="Your Total Payment" readonly/><hr>
        </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **DON'T** rely on javascript calculations. Use this for information purpose, but recalculate the value, once the request is submitted. Everybody with a little experience can modify values generated with javascript.

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you can avoid errors like this.

Comment: As @AlexMcMillan said, get in the habit of properly indenting your code - you'll do everyone a favour...including yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing your function. Add  `}` before `</Script>`. You should also use lower case in your tag `</script>`.

Comment: Also don't recommend using camel case on those script tags.  `</Script>`

Comment: it's multiply not add

Comment: @ficuscr that's not camelCase.

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry.  Don't capitalize that.  Assume it works but it looks "wrong".